# Can I use phonertc to send arbitrary data?

Tags: phonertc

I'm trying to use Phonegap/Cordova to send data between mobile and desktop application and between mobile to mobile via local network (just local p2p).

I've seen that in phonertc I can pick video/audio streams between devices, but what if I want to send regular objects through - or maybe using http://peerjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and perhaps you've moved on with your requirements; but I think what you were looking for was [socket.io P2P](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-p2p/).